# Variable declaration using static keyword

Tags: c, static

```
void main()
{
    static int a=5;
    printf("%i",a--);
    if(a)
        main();
}
```

This program prints 54321. Can anybody explain why?

Comment: Assuming it's C or C++. If you know what `static` means, you know the answer. Go read a book. It's also not a good idea to call `main` recursively.

Comment: If you don't take anything else away from this experience, notice how the accepted answerer, IMHO apparently, was not able to answer this question, but was able to by searching the internet and assuming the language. Don't hesitate to put forth effort to find answers yourself.

Comment: Just check it out what is static keyword `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable` and how recursion performed on to the stack`http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/6.RECURSION.html`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming C/C++, I found this [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html):

> (1) The use of static inside a function ... means that once the variable has been initialized, it remains in memory until the end of the program. You can think of it as saying that the variable sticks around, maintaining its value, until the program completely ends. For instance, you can use a static variable to record the number of times a function has been called simply by including the lines static int count =0; and count++; inside the function.
>
> (2) Because count is a static variable, the line "static int count = 0;" will only be executed once. Whenever the function is called, count will have the last value assigned to it.

So, two things going on: from (1), `a` will stick around for the whole program. From (2), the declaration/initialization of `a` will happen exactly once, at the beginning. Subsequent recursive calls on your function will not redeclare/reinitialize `a`.

Comment: Where is the `count` you're referring to? Is it possible to change the value of a `static` variable during one or more of the recursive calls to `main`; if so, how do I do it. If I can, and do, change it what happens the next time I call `main`? Do you know?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: A `static` variable within a function may be changed just as any other variable declared within that function.  The only difference is that the `static` variable is only initialized when the program starts up, and therefore its value persists between function calls, which means the next time `main` is called it'll have the value you change it to.

Comment: "Where is the count you're referring to?" -- It's an example he gave. "I was just testing Ken." -- That's not the purpose of these comments. If you downvoted this, that was wrong and you should remove the downvote ... this is a correct, useful answer, and downvoting is for answers that aren't useful (hover over the down arrow and it will tell you that).

Comment: "The lack of any real personalized content" -- that is simply false; the last paragraph is real personalized content. "is suspicious" -- It's your behavior that is "suspicious". Where did you get the idea that it's your job to police the originality of answers by new members of SO?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: From what I've been able to gather on SO, it's helpful to have supporting documentation for one's position, so I found it and chose to use its words in (1) and (2) instead of my own while still citing the source. I edited (1) slightly to get to the point faster, but didn't edit (2) to properly reflect the original post due to tiredness. (Obviously the last para is mine.) It's what I get for attempting to answer something entirely too late at night, so, sorry for that. @_@

Comment: @JimBalter, if you'd like to direct comments you can do it with@. count: It's not an example *he* gave, it's an direct copy from the link. testing: it's ok to ask for clarification, that was an additional comment (deleted). downvote: usefulness is subjective as are votes; I don't find plagiarized content useful; thanks. lacking: read the definition of the word; it doesn't mean void of. originality: are you [serious](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)? That's *all* our jobs.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Now it looks like _you_ need to read a definition of a word. I didn't plagiarize anything since I cited the source, and context was clear that (1) and (2) came from that source.

Comment: OP & @Jim Balter this post is under discussion on Meta. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268904/what-is-the-limit-of-copying-outside-links

Comment: @eddie_cat Thanks but I have nothing further to add and no interest in continuing discussion about it.

Comment: @eddie_cat: Thanks for letting us know!

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is tagged C, here's an answer from the C standard:

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier `_Thread_local`, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class specifier `static`, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.
>
> §6.2.4

Answer (score 1):

```
void func()
{
    static int a=5;
    printf("%i",a--);
    if(a)
        func();
}
```

Let's get rid of the `main()` issue and call it `func()` instead.

Declaring something `static` means that the variable will retain its value between function calls.
The first time `func()` is called, `a` will be assigned the value `5`.
The `a--` decrements it to `4` after it's printed, and if `a!= 0`, `func()` will be called again. Note that `func()` is calling itself before it exits.
This repeats recursively until `a==0`, at which time it will exit all instances of the function.

Google "recursive function c++" for some in depth explanations.